# How to parse JSON Array when the number of keys change every time an API call is made?

Tags: ios, json, swift

So I'm trying to parse JSON in swift and my API call gives me a JSON array dictionary which contains the names of nearby wifi networks.
My question is, the number of networks at different places will be different , so how to parse this JSON array so that after parsing Im able to display all the available wifi network names as individual cells in TableView.
P.S: I don't want to use SwiftJSON library

My JSON is:

```
{
 "networks": 
  [
   "WiFi network 1",
   "WiFi network 2",
   "WiFi network 3",
  ],
}
```

My JSON parsing is as follows,

```
func downloadSettingsDetails(completed: @escaping DownloadSettingsComplete) {
    Alamofire.request(SETTINGS_DATA_URL).responseJSON { response in
        let result = response.result
        print(response.description)

        if let dictDetails = result.value as? Dictionary<String , AnyObject> {

            if let networks = dictDetails["networks"] as? String {

            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Those are arrays. So load the object with key "network" into an array and you're all set.

Comment: Use the `NSJSONSerialization`, since it is an array use the count property to get the number of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value under the `networks` key is an array. If you parse it as an array instead of as a specific object, then you can have an array of `String`. Afterwards, you can get the amount with the `.count` property to get how many networks are there.

For example, you could do something like the following, using `guards` for safety:

```
func downloadSettingsDetails(completed: @escaping DownloadSettingsComplete) {
    Alamofire.request(SETTINGS_DATA_URL).responseJSON { response in
        let result = response.result
        print(response.description)

        guard let json = result as? NSDictionary, let networks = json["networks"] as? [String] else {
            return
        }

        //Do what you want with the networks array  
}
```